# Customining devise creating action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my controller in action create i have the following code

```
def create
    params[:user].merge!(verified: true)
    super
  end
```

On my form i have checkbox with name `tos_agreement`. How do i force devise not to save resource in super if my tos_agreement value in params != '1' but do render instead with adding an error to @user.errors ?

I can't use model method with implementing such checkboxes, so i have to handle it via controller without rewritting devise's super method

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validates_acceptance_of` provided within rails. Check it out [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_acceptance_of)

Comment: as i said i can't do any validation within model, only controller available to be changed

Comment: Then something like this
`redirect_to root_path, :flash => {:error => "Please accept T&C"} and return if false`

Comment: in this case i will lose everything in instance var @user, errors, form-data, etc

Comment: tried to do that, but here is what i get in console
`Processing by UsersController#index as */*
[Devise] Could not find devise mapping for path "/users".
Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example:

devise_scope :user do
  match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
end

Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms

AbstractController::ActionNotFound - Could not find devise mapping for path "/users".
Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example:

devise_scope :user do
  match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
end`